# Get JSON as well as XML response using Django Restframework

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, xml, django-rest-framework

I am working on creating an API, where I can return Json response as well as XML response based upon what format is needed.

Settings.py file -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'geoapp',
'rest_framework_xml',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

View.py file -

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def nominationurl(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return Response("GET Remark")

elif request.method == 'POST':
    dict1 = {}
    dict1['data'] = model.objects.values()
    dict1['format'] = request.data['format']
    return Response(dict1)

    # {"format" : "json"}
    # {"format" : "xml"}
```

Here I get normal Json response. But I want to decide type of response from POST request ie when {"format" : "json"} is posted I should get Json response and when {"format" : "xml"} is posted I should get XML response.

I tried searching for the correct response but it is not working. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [renderers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) for that.

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer, XMLRenderer))
def someview(request):
    dict1 = {'some': 'data'}
    return Response(dict1)
```

Then set "Accept" header to "application/json" or "application/xml" on your request.

```
curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8000/api/someview/' --header 'Accept: application/xml'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><some>data</some></root>

curl --location --request GET 'localhost:8000/api/someview/' --header Accept: application/json'

{"some":"data"}
```

**UPD** You can create your own [content negotiator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/) that will choose the renderer by the data in request.

*negotiation.py*

```
from rest_framework.negotiation import DefaultContentNegotiation


class CustomContentNegotiation(DefaultContentNegotiation):
    def select_renderer(self, request, renderers, format_suffix=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if format:=request.data.get('format'):
                for renderer in self.filter_renderers(renderers, format):
                    if format==renderer.format:
                        return renderer,renderer.media_type
        return super().select_renderer(request, renderers, format_suffix)
```

Add your XMLRenderer to settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer'
    ],
```

Then you can set negotiation globally

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    <...>
    'DEFAULT_CONTENT_NEGOTIATION_CLASS': 'your_project.negotiation.CustomContentNegotiation',
}
```

Or in specific APIView

```
class SomeClassView(APIView):
    content_negotiation_class = CustomContentNegotiation

    def post(self, request):
        dict1 = {'some': 'data'}
        return Response(dict1)
```

Comment: I have to send Json / XML is post request as param, second half of your answer wont work for me.@Mur4al

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to bypass standard HTTP negotiation through json, but updated the answer.